# selenium 1 click on span issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

Have problem when trying to click on span element(an element "helpful" from list of "rate translation" button on http://translate.google.com/)!
Remote control is saying that element was clicked but nothing really happened.
Code:

```
 selenium.MouseDown("xpath=//div[@id='gt-res-rate']/div/div/div/div/span");
 selenium.Click("css=#gt-rate-helpful-text");
```

Tryed MouseDown, GetEval, and RunScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is from what I can see that the element has a display: none style set on it, and clicking on an element with a display: none will do nothing.  You would have to put in some text to be translated first.  If text was inserted then the click event should work properly.

-------------------  EDIT --------------------

```
        browserDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|a");
        browserDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='gt-res-rate']/div/div/div/div/span")).Click();
        browserDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='gt-rate-helpful-text']")).Click();
```

I tested the above code and everything worked fine.

Comment: sorry, I put only a part of the code, of course i put some text to translate and push translate button

Comment: This would be true if the code was using Selenium's WebDriver API, but it appears that it is using the Selenium RC API instead, which doesn't enforce a visibility requirement.